# The rig rotates automatically when the desired pole target is set in Inverse kinematics

Tags: modeling, rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I was rigging my character seeing the tutorial by CG Geek https://youtu.be/SBYb1YmaOMY?t=450. The same process was done but my rig rotates out of model[image]

[image: Before]

Comment: do you mean you've parented and nothing happens? or the IK doesn't work as expected? Don't forget to set the correct Chain length for the IK. If it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: As @moonboots pointed out , the problem was not setting the correct chain length.

Comment: Yes, I needed to set the chain length . It was not given in tutorial. Thanks